# Move all content to the right on mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How do I move all the content to the right to make space for a menu in the left side? What I am trying to do is have a menu similar to the one on http://mashable.com/ on the mobile view. You can resize the window and try to see what I am talking about. 
Thank you

Marius

Comment: How could we possibly help? Do you use a framework? Do you know about responsive design? Media queries?

Comment: Of course I do. I use bootstrap and all the programming is done in jquery (integrated 1.11.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to have your content wrapped in a master div to which you apply css3 transitions.

for example:

```
<div id="contentWrap"> ... content ... </div>
```

css:

```
#contentWrap{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    transform: translate(0%, 0);
}

#contentWrap.open{
    transform: translate(80%, 0);
}
```

now you can bind a click handler on the element that moves in/out the content by removing or adding the '.open' class to the '#contentWrap' div

Comment: So I all I gotta do is this? For my mashable.com example, I should replace 80% with 50% and that's it? This and 2 lines of Jquery?

Comment: Of course you would also have to have your menu on the page and either: make it move in the same way as the content (with wrapping div and css transition) OR have it behind the content using z-index and only move the content div.

Comment: I will use z-index. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

try using [Menufication](http://cko.me/Menufication-Responsive-Fly-Out-Menu-Download_52af80036b40fe1150009bcf) which animates the menu and pushes the content